# php's problem (server error)

Tags: php

When I type this code,the server displays "Internal Server Error"

```
function line($tec,$text,$array)
{

global $html;

$pos= strpos($html,$text);
$len=strlen($text);
$p=$pos;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) 
{

if($array[$i]->get_Technique() == $tec)

{if($array[$i]->get_source() == $text)
$p=strpos($html,$text,(int)$p+$len);

if ($p===0 or $p===false or $p===""){return -1;}

}}

$pos=$p;
$result=substr($html,0,$pos);
$lineNum=substr_count($result,"\n");
return $lineNum+1  ;

}
```

what's the problem?

Comment: [Here's how you can see what the actual error message is.](http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-display-php-errors-in-my-script-code-when-display-errors-is-disabled-t453.html)

Answer (score 1):

`what is the problem in this code:`, 6th line down.

If you want to add comments, prefix them with `//` (`// comment here`) or surround them with `/* ...`*/ (`/* comment here */`).

**Edit after your edit**

Syntactically, the code is fine. Probably some function you are calling is raising the error but without sufficient information it is impossible to tell. Get a better error message (turn on debugging/error logging on the server).

Comment: I think that was just thrown in there for the sake of the question.

Comment: 6th line down What do you mean any line? I did not write any comment

Answer (score 0):

maybe one of those two calls doesn't call a method (that's a thing that returns an error in php)

```
$array[$i]->get_Technique()
$array[$i]->get_source()
```

One has a capitol, the other doesn't.